Which OAuth flow to use for on-prem web apps and Google login?
We are building an application that has a web UI and gets installed on-premise by customers. We want to support customers' employees to log into the application using their (work) Google accounts, assuming customers that are using Google mail/drive/etc. already. Using either OAuth for a user data endpoint, or OpenID Connect, would be fine, but AFAIK they seem to use the same authorization mechanism at Google anyway.
This question is about choosing the correct OAuth flow and conceptually understanding the information exchange, not about choosing a particular implementation library.
The application consists of a backend that runs on customers' servers and a frontend that runs in their employees' browsers.
I have previously understood the Authorization Code flow (with PKCE) for SaaS applications and it looks that this is roughly, but not exactly, the flow that I need. Arguments in favor of that are:

since the application has a backend running on the server, exchanging the authorization code for an access token through the back-channel is possible
the frontend runs in the browser, so accessing Google's web UI is technically possible
This article by auth0.com states that the authorization code flow is the correct choice for a web application running on a server: https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/which-oauth-2-0-flow-should-i-use

However, I can see two things that are different for on-prem web software than for SaaS, stemming from the fact that we cannot expect each customer to register their application installation as a client with Google:

the application must be considered a public client, so we cannot have it authenticate against Google using a client secret. Not using such a secret makes the flow inherently less secure. As far as I understand, PKCE should mitigate this problem to some extent. Is there anything else I can do in my particular situation to further mitigate that problem? Will Google accept authorization requests without a client secret?
the registration screen for OAuth clients at Google wants me to enter "authorized JavaScript origins" and "Authorized redirect URLs". For SaaS having a single authorized redirect URL totally makes sense, but each of our customers independently chooses a local domain name or even IP address to run our software at, so I cannot enter that here.

How should I deal with these problems? Is registering the client with Google needed / the right thing in my case? Is using the authorization code flow even the right thing to do?
